# how to extract a specific part of a string from character 7 to 17 and save it in new txt file (findstr, gnu32-sed or other tool)

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, regex, sed, findstr

How do I extract a specific part of a string from character 7 - 17 using regex via the command line?

My string is `ThisString` and in the file data I have a lot of strings, but I need only `ThisString` instead of the whole line `Value: ThisString5NotThis`

```bat
Value: ThisString5NotThis
Details: other_str
Number: xxx
Value: ThisString5NotThis
Details: other_str
Number: xxx
Value: ThisString5NotThis
Details: other_str
Number: xxx
Value: ThisString5NotThis
Details: other_str
Number: xxx
```

For now, I've used `findstr`, but it extracts the whole line with the whole string

```bat
FindStr Value: "data.txt" > "done.txt"
```

Or is there another tool to extract part of a string from one file to another 
 via `sed` in Cygwin?

Comment: Unclear: Do you want to extract `ThisString` or `ThisString5NotThis`?

Comment: `findstr` supports regex via `/R` _(see `findstr /?` or it's [man page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr))_

Comment: @harrymc only `ThisString`

Comment: @JW0914 i did try and didn't work

Comment: Unclear. Why do you to find a string in order to extract itself?

Comment: @harrymc I dont understand your what do You mean, Sir? I just need part of string in other words string string from character 7 to 17 only this in every 1, 4, 7 etc line

Comment: f@harrymc I don't understand what you are asking him either. The first question you ask him "Do you want to extract ThisString or ThisString5NotThis"  is strange because obviously he can adapt it and this site doesn't want questions to be so specific that they are no use to anybody else, And the other question you ask him " Why do you to find a string in order to extract itself?" makes no sense

Comment: @Tom if you can get the 'cut' command, that comes with cygwin (or gnuwin32 coreutils though cygwin tends to be more up to date) then you can do `echo abcdefg | cut -b 2-4`  and that gives `bcd` that may be of some use

Comment: @Tom also `echo abcdefg | sed -r "s/.(...).*/\1/"` gives `bcd`

Comment: your question is very unclear and not matching other things you write, because you said in comment "in every 1, 4, 7 etc line" then you  describe a solution as "working beautiful" when it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first thing that came to my mind:

`grep "^Value: " data.txt | sed 's/^.\{7\}//' | sed 's/\(.\{10\}\).*/\1/'`

- grep: only lines beginning with "Value: "
- sed 1: remove first 7 chars
- sed 2: find two substrings with 10 chars and the rest. Replace both with first substring.

**added**

**Tom commented** "Why this command delete carriage return CR and leave only LF (line feed). "

**Caleb answers**
Because the .* wildcard also matches the CR character. You can simply add it again: `grep "^Value: " test.txt | sed 's/^.\{7\}//' | sed 's/\(.\{10\}\).*/\1\x0d/'`

Comment: He said in comment  and quite a while before you posted, that he wants it "in every 1, 4, 7 "  line. And  You should not post just "first thing that comes to mind".

Comment: It's a solution with 'sed' and it works :-P

Comment: @Caleb its working beautiful :) but I have one more question. Why this command delete carriage return CR and leave only LF (line feed). Here is my screen from notepad++ [link to my screenshot](https://prnt.sc/rpg17p)

Comment: @Tom Because the .* wildcard also matches the CR character. You can simply add it again: `grep "^Value: " test.txt | sed 's/^.\{7\}//' | sed 's/\(.\{10\}\).*/\1\x0d/'`

Comment: @Tom you asked in comment re particular lines, this doesn't do particular lines so why are you saying it works?

Comment: @Caleb You write " the .* wildcard also matches the CR character." <-- Are you sure?. sed might not match any CR or LF.  see `echo -e 'abc\ndef' | sed "s/\n/f/"` contrast with `echo -e 'abc\ndef' | sed "s/b/f/"`

Comment: @barlop beacuse its works, try by your self. Thanks Caleb one again. You save my hard drive :)

Comment: @barlop You are trying to match the LF character, which does not work. But still the wildcard matches the CR character: `echo -e "test\r\n" | sed 's/.*//' > test.txt`

Comment: @Tom so you shouldn't have asked about particular lines then when that wasn't your requirement

Comment: @Caleb I like the adding in of CR that you did there. I suppose an alternative might be using `[^\r]*` or `[^\x0d]*` in place of dot, in the find portion?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen in the screenshot you put in comment above that you're using Notepad++.

Here is a way to do the job:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^Value: (.{10}).+?(?=\RValue|\z)`
- Replace with: `$1`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **CHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
  Value:    # literally "Value: " (with a space)
  (.{10})   # group 1, 10 any characters
  .+?       # 1 or more any characters
  (?=       # positive lookahead, make sure we have after:
    \R        # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
    Value     # literally
   |        # OR
    \z        # end of file
  )         # end lookahead
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1      # content of group 1, the data to keep
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: @downvoter: any reason, doesn't this work?

Comment: strange why downvote if this work?

Comment: @Tom: I don't know :-(. If it works for you, you can upvote and accept the answer. [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: @Toto The flaw should be very clear just looking at his first line, you must have noticed it yourself too. I downvoted you, because his very first line said "How do I extract a specific part of a string ...... **via the command line**?" (note the "via the command line"), and you gave him a workaround given that he asked for "via the command line". Even if he uses notepad++, he asked what he asked.

Comment: @barlop: Does it really deserve a downvote?

Comment: @Toto by my standards, absolutely. A question states a requirement and an "answer" ignores the requirement, and not only that but the requirement is very prominent in the question, even in the first line. That's right and wrong, of course things can get a bit cloudy in peoples' minds when the questioner themselves state requirements they don't have and don't ask what they mean and so on. But one is meant to answer the question asked (and if that helps the asker, then so be it, and if not then they should fix their question)..